# My for loop seems to not be incrementing. It gets stuck on 2 (project euler 14)

Tags: c, debugging

I am working on project euler #14 :

**Question:**

The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:

n → n/2 (n is even)
n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)

Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following sequence:

13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 10 terms. Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem), it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.

Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?

NOTE: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one million.

**Problem:**

When I run this code, the first for loop runs as expected. But then the variable `num` seems to not increment in the for loop and stays on 2 (which isn't even in the perameters of num I gave to start out with), giving the output:

```
2
0

1
1
```

repeating over and over again. Not sure why this is happening and can't find anything online.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int maxcount = 0;
    for (int num = 5; num < 2000000; num++) {
        printf("%d\n0\n\n", num);
        int count = 0;
        while (num >= 1) {
            count++;
            if (num == 2) {
                num = 1;
                printf("1\n%d\n\n", count);
            }
            if (num > 1) {
                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                    num = num / 2;
                    printf("%d\n%d\n\n", num, count);
                }
                else {
                    num = (3 * num) + 1;
                    printf("%d\n%d\n\n", num, count);
                }
            }
            if (num == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxcount) {
            maxcount = count;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", maxcount);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It *does* increment... from 1, which is the value it has when you reach the bottom of the `for` loop body. 1+1 = 2.

Comment: Copy the loop control `num` to another variable.

Comment: You're modifying your loop variable, `num`, inside the loop.  So of course the next iteration won't pick up where the previous left off.  You need to use a *different variable* if you want to modify it.  E.g. `num2 = num;`  Then modify `num2`, leaving `num` alone so the next iteration won't be affected.

Comment: Thanks guys! Still new to coding so I need all the help I can get

Comment: The best way to catch things like this is to ask yourself, what will this do?  If you think clearly about it, you will catch things like this.  Trace it through, and you will see that `num` will be incorrect on the next iteration.  That will lead to a deeper understanding than having someone else point it out to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce a new variable. You are doing:

```
for (int num = 5; num < 2000000; num++) {
    /* collatz stuff, which modifies num, and eventually
       causes it to become 1
    */
}
```

so when the `num++` portion of the `for` loop runs, `num` becomes 2.

What you want is

```
for (int start = 5 ; start < 2000000 ; start++) {
    int num = start;
    /* collatz stuff, which modifies num */
}
```

since the variable `start` is never modified by the loop body, it will keep going up in sequence by 1, without interference.

Comment: Thanks, now it's been pointed out it seems so obvious... Thanks so much though, not sure how long it would've taken me to see that

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop, you change the value of the loop variable (`num`).

You start with `num = 5`, and the inner while loop then follows Collatz's rules and gets to 1, at which point the while-loop ends.

Then the for-loop ends, and `num` is incremented to 2 by `num++`, and the next iteration of the loop begins.

In the second iteration, the while-loop immediately sees `num == 2`, so it sets `num = 1`, and the while loop ends. Then the for-loop ends, incrementing `num` to 2, and the cycle continues forever.

As others have said, you just need to leave the loop variable alone and use a different variable in the inner loop.